# Simple 4x4x4 OLL parity algs?

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I am learning to solve a 4x4x4 Rubik's cube and I think that the beginner OLL parity alg:

```
(r U2 x r U2 r' U2 l U2 r' U2 r U2 r' U2 r')
```

is a little too complex.

**Does anyone know a simpler alg for it?**

Answer (score 5):

> r' U2 l F2 l' F2 r2 U2 r U2 r' U2 F2 r2 F2

Super simple! (corrected version)

Comment: Papa Crescendo’s YouTube channel has a great way to memorise this algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the simplest:

> r U2 x r U2 r U2 r' U2 l U2 r' U2 r U2 r' U2 r'

Unless this works:

> r2 F2 U2 r' F' u L' U2 L u' F' r' U2 r2 F2 r

You can find all the 4x4x4 parity algorithms [here](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/4x4x4_Parity_Algorithms).

Comment: see my reply to your response (specifically regarding information about the algorithm which you posted as being easy to remember).  Of course, you are probably aware of the DP algorithm (that is just a 4 move sequence repeated 5 times) that I found two months after you posted this response (which I mention in my answer to this topic's question), so maybe you think that's easier than the one you listed.  I'm obviously a little late in posting this, but better late than never!

Answer (score 2):

I am grateful that Redline provided a link to my wikipage!

> And I have a story about [the algorithm](https://alg.cubing.net/?puzzle=4x4x4&alg=r2_F2_U2_r-_F-_u_L-_U2_L_u-_F-_r-_U2_r2_F2_r) he thinks/thought was easy
> to remember.  YES, it works.  I found it along with many other algorithms by using
> Cube Explorer for the 3x3x3.  Unlike many 4x4x4 OLL parity algorithms
> which people have gotten from 3x3x3 solvers, this one was not obvious
> to translate to the 4x4x4.  As you can see, it has some very unusual
> turns; and it is very unique!  See it on my wikipage for more details!

On that page, one can find a **4 move** algorithm which needs to be repeated 5 times to fix *double* parity.  But [here is my original post about it on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cubers/comments/7mda6x/by_far_the_easiest_oll_parity_alg_to_memorize_for/).

One of the algorithms in that list is

> [Rw' (F2 U' Lw' U)5 Rw](https://alg.cubing.net/?puzzle=4x4x4&alg=Rw-_(F2_U-_Lw-_U)5_Rw), for example.

For those who want a "pure version" as George A. Solodun does, I actually derived the above double parity algorithm from an algorithm Floyd Newberry came up with for the "pure" edge flip case.

> [(Rw B' z')(2R' F U2 F')4 2R' (z B Rw')](https://alg.cubing.net/?puzzle=4x4x4&alg=(Rw_B-_z-)(2R-_F_U2_F-)4_2R-_(z_B_Rw-))

***If you don't know the notation of these algorithms, GREAT.  That's fine.  Just click the links and observe.***

Answer (score 0):

> (Rr)2 B2 U2 (Ll) U2 (Rr)' U2 (Rr) U2 F2 (Rr) F2 (Ll)' B2 (Rr)2

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not a strict OLL parity alg, as it reorients two corners and permutes two corners and edges.