# Early OLL parity detection and correction

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm, twisty-puzzles, mechanical-puzzles

Is it possible to detect the OLL parity of a scrambled 3x3 cube directly?
I have reduced the 4x4 cube to a 3x3 cube. How can I check the parity of the resulting 3x3 cube - to check if an edge has been flipped?

Comment: These are two distinct questions; an answer can address one without addressing the other at all. Perhaps you could [edit] to remove one question, then [ask a new question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) which contains the other one. You may [link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) the questions together. On this site, there should be only one question within each question, that way answerers may focus on a single question, and there can be a single best answer per question.

Comment: Your first question is answered [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/53847/20814).

Comment: Your second question is answewred [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/55763/20814), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64536/20814), and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/90120/20814).